# css html lyout with divs and same class

Tags: css, html

Please help. I want to achieve that text and button on yellow box be alligned left and right (text on left side - margin 20 px; button on right side - margin 20 px) and menu in footer aligned with yellow box.

I can't add picture, sorry.

Edit: Added JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wqBEf/

This is my css code:

```
        #page
    {
        width: 960px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #page > #main
    {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 650px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #main > #inner
    {
        margin: 20px;

    }

    #page-title h1
    {
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer-hotline
    {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(255,207,0);
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #999999;

        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 650px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #footer-hotline > .part
    {
        float: left; width: 33%;
        margin-left: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #footer-hotline > .part input
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    #footer
    {
        margin-top: -25px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 25px;
        background-color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #footer > .link
    {
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #footer > .link > div
    {
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

And this is my html code:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="page-title">
            <img src="myLogo.png" alt="Schulz logo" />
            <h1>Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">RenderBody</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="f-c"></div>       
</div>
<div id="footer-hotline">
    <div class="part">Hotline: 0800/888 888</div>
    <div class="part"><input type="submit" class="button" id="callback-button" value="callback" name="callback-button" /></div>
</div> 
<div class="f-c"></div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="link"><div><a href="#">GTC</a></div></div>
    <div class="link"><div><a href="#">About</a></div></div>
    <div class="link"><div><a href="#">Help</a></div></div>
    <div class="link"><div><a href="#">Language</a></div></div>
</div>
```

Thanx for answers, suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `:first-child` pseudo-class for the issue of getting the two items to work together (this will only work if you have only two at any one time).  It's also well supported [going back to IE7](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/)

You also need to implement `float:right`, `direction:rtl`, and `margin-right`:

```
#footer-hotline > .part
{
    float: right; width: 33%;
    direction: rtl;             
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer-hotline > .part:first-child
{
    direction: ltr;
    float: left;      
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[Eli Gassert's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978193/css-html-lyout-with-divs-and-same-class#answer-13978384) answer should suffice for centering the nav

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ2Uz/ 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ2Uz/show

Comment: I can't figure out how to line up menu item in footer to left footer-hotline yellow box. Could you help me about that to? Now if menu is growing at one moment fall down on right side.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wqBEf/1/ for an update.

Noteworthy changes.

- I added `left align-left` and `right align-right` classes set for float and for text alignment, respectively.
- I set your links to `display: inline` because it is the easiest way to center a list of items horizontally.

Those were the main two changes.  The rest of the changes were just to support the above two, such as removing/adding some margins.

Comment: Great! Eli thanx for very quick answer.